# Is this a bug on RubyMonk or something flaw in my logic thinking?

Tags: logic

I am learning Ruby with Rubymonk.com

Below is the project description:

Hiring Programmers - Boolean Expressions in Ruby

Let us say you are trying to recruit team-members for your new startup! Given a candidate, you need an expression that will tell you whether they fit into certain types. This is how a candidate object would look:

```
candidate.years_of_experience = 4
candidate.github_points = 293
candidate.languages_worked_with = ['C', 'Ruby', 'Python', 'Clojure']
candidate.applied_recently? = false
candidate.age = 26
```

We are looking to hire experienced Ruby programmers. Our ideal candidate has 2 or more years of experience, but some programmers become really good even before that. We'll consider their Github points (a nice indicator of a good programmer), and even if they are not experienced, candidates with 500 Github points or more can apply. And there is one more catch: Ruby being a cool and awesome language, a lot of smart youngsters are very good at it. We love those kids, but for this particular job we'd rather have them study at school than work. Let us filter out candidates who are younger than 15. Also we don't want to consider candidates who applied recently for this opening.

Base on above description, I conclude that items listed below must be true:

1. candidate.languages_worked_with.include?('Ruby')
2. candidate.years_of_exprience >= 2 || candidate.github_points >= 500
3. candidate.age > 15
4. candidate.applied_recently? == false

And my answer is:

```
is_an_experienced_programmer = (candidate.years_of_exprience >= 2 
|| candidate.github_points >= 500) && candidate.languages_worked_with.include? 'Ruby' 
&& (candidate.age > 15) && !(candidate.applied_recently?)
```

but then answer is:

```
is_an_experienced_ruby_programmer =  (candidate.years_of_experience >= 2 
|| candidate.github_points >= 500) && (candidate.languages_worked_with.include? 'Ruby') 
&& ! (candidate.age < 15 || candidate.applied_recently?)
```

The only difference between my answer and the answer is:

```
 (candidate.age > 15) && !(candidate.applied_recently?)
```

above saying candidate must older than 15 and haven't applied recently.

and the answer:

```
! (candidate.age < 15 || candidate.applied_recently?)
```

above code basically saying, candidate can not younger than 15 and haven't applied recently.

Aren't they the same? Or something flawed in my logic?

Comment: Almost same; `15` is neither under `15`, nor over `15`. Changing `>` to `>=` makes them equivalent. See [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: Thanks, Renzo, do you mean ' (candidate.age >= 15) && !(candidate.applied_recently?)' is equivalent to'! (candidate.age < 15 || candidate.applied_recently?)'

Comment: Interesting enough that when I wrote the code like this, I passed the test: 'is_an_experienced_ruby_programmer =  (candidate.years_of_experience >= 2 || candidate.github_points >= 500) && (candidate.languages_worked_with.include? 'Ruby') && !candidate.applied_recently? && (candidate.age > 15)'

Answer (score 0):

Its almost same only thing you are missing is >=

```
(candidate.age >= 15) && !(candidate_applied_recently?)
```

and that's why you might be getting the wrong answer.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that, but it gets the same result as my code. I suspect it is a bug on RubyMonk's checking the code if it make no difference in logical manner.

Comment: RubyMonk may be checking the code instead of testing the output.

Answer (score 0):

I conclude that there is something wrong in the Testing Logic with the project on RubyMonk:
When I use the code below, I passed the test:

```
is_an_experienced_ruby_programmer =  (candidate.years_of_experience >= 2 || candidate.github_points >= 500) && (candidate.languages_worked_with.include? 'Ruby') && !candidate.applied_recently? && (candidate.age > 15)
```

And when I use below, I failed the test:

```
is_an_experienced_programmer = (candidate.years_of_exprience >= 2 || candidate.github_points >= 500) && (candidate.languages_worked_with.include? 'Ruby') && (candidate.age > 15) && !(candidate.applied_recently?)
```

So

```
!(candidate.applied_recently?) && (candidate.age > 15)
```

is different to

```
(candidate.age > 15) && !(candidate.applied_recently?)
```

in Rubymonk's mind?